# Evaluating $\int \frac{1}{9+4x^2} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

> Evaluate $$\int \dfrac{1}{9+4x^2} dx$$

I let $u = 9 + 4x^2$ so $du$ would be $8x$. But I don't know any way to make the numerator $1$ become $8x$. I could multiply by $1/8$ but then I'd still need the $x$ to have $du/u$.

Comment: Do you know how to evaluate $\int \frac{1}{1+u^2} \, du$?  What substitution, plus some algebra, could reduce the problem to such an integral?

Answer (score 1):

$$\int\frac{dx}{9+4x^2}=\frac19\int\frac{dx}{1+\left(\frac{2x}3\right)^2}$$

Use [Trigonometric substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_substitution),

$$\frac{2x}3=\tan\theta$$

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{1}{4} \displaystyle \int \frac{1}{(x^2+ \frac{9}{4} )}$ dx

You get it directly through $\frac{1}{4}$ $\tan^{-1}$$\frac
 {2x}{3}$

Answer (score 0):

You're going in the wrong direction. Hint: Rewrite the integral as

$\frac{1}{9} \displaystyle \int \frac{1}{(1 + \frac{4}{9} x^2)}$ dx

Let $u = \frac{2}{3} x$.